# Background for Lie Algebra cohomology and de Rham cohomology of compact Lie Groups

Tags: algebraic-topology, soft-question, differential-topology, lie-groups

I have read that the de-Rham cohomology of compact Lie Groups is isomorphic to the Lie Algebra cohomology of its Lie Algebra. Do I need the knowledge of singular cohomology to understand this?

I think that de Rham's theorem (and so singular cohomology) is needed to understand the isomorphism of the de-Rham cohomology to left invariant forms, right? But do you use that in the above isomorphism (to Lie Algebra cohomology)?

Comment: You should read the actual paper by Chevelley and Eilenberg, which is **extremely** readable.

Comment: I will, thanks for the reference!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think you need to pass through singular cohomology, this is all about de Rham complexes, and here's how the proof goes. Let $G$ be a connected compact Lie group and $\mathfrak{g}$ the corresponding Lie algebra. There are two different steps:

1. Easy part: note that the complex $\Omega_L^\bullet (G) \subset \Omega^\bullet (G)$ formed by the left invariant differential forms is essentially the same as the standard Chevalley-Eilenberg complex calculating the Lie algebra cohomology $H^\bullet (\mathfrak{g}, \mathbb{R})$.
2. Trickier part: the natural subcomplex inclusion $i\colon \Omega_L^\bullet (G) \to \Omega^\bullet (G)$ induces isomorphisms in cohomology. For this we consider a morphism of complexes $p\colon \Omega^\bullet (G) \to \Omega_L^\bullet (G)$ that from a given differential form $\alpha$ produces a left-invariant differential form. This is known as the "averaging map", and it is defined by the "Haar integral" 
   $$p\colon \alpha \mapsto \int_G L_g^* \alpha$$
   ---and for this we need $G$ to be compact! First of all, $p\circ i$ is identity, and as for $i\circ p$, it is possible to construct an explicit chain homotopy equivalence between $i\circ p$ and the identity map.

A possible detailed reference: Werner Greub, Stephen Halperin, Ray Vanstone, ``Connections, Curvature, and Cohomology'', vol. II, Chapter IV.

P.S. Yes, [the original paper of Chevalley and Eilenberg](http://www.ams.org/journals/tran/1948-063-01/S0002-9947-1948-0024908-8/) is probably the most accessible account.

Comment: Great answer, thank you very much!